# Anonymous modules and classes garbage collection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, module, garbage-collection, anonymous-class

I'd like to know why the following code apparently doesn't garbage collect anonymous modules that are supposedly not referenced anywhere anymore (not extended/included, not named, containing array set to nil).

I'd appreciate if anyone could clarify what's going on under the hood with relatively simple/general programming words. Is there a special ruby way to achieve this ? Can't anonymous modules/classes be garbage collected no matter what ? Or was i simply mislead by the memory stats i got ?

NOTE : i'm using ruby 1.9.3 ; don't know if ruby 2.x would change anything at all...
NOTE 2 : the result is the same whether or not the module defines the foo method

Thanks in advance.

```
puts("INITIAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects}")


i = 100000
ms = []

i.times do
    ms << Module.new do
        def foo()
             puts('foo method called')
        end
    end
end

puts("#{i} MODULES CREATED")
puts("OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects}")

ms = nil
ObjectSpace.garbage_collect

puts("#{i} MODULES GARBAGE COLLECTED")
puts("WAITING TO END PROGRAM")

stop = gets
puts("FINAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects}")
```

I say "apparently doesn't garbage collect" because my OS task manager doesn't show any reduction in memory usage from the process, and calling ObjectSpace.count_objects yields the following, which i read (wrongly so ?) as : no the memory used by your modules has not been freed.

> INITIAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : {:TOTAL=>14730, :FREE=>251, :T_OBJECT=>8, :T_CLASS=>542, :T_MODULE=>21, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>6349, :T_REGEXP=>24, :T_ARRAY=>1009, :T_HASH=>14, :T_BIGNUM=>3, :T_FILE=>10, :T_DATA=>408, :T_MATCH=>108, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>5956, :T_ICLASS=>19}
>
> 100000 MODULES CREATED
>
> OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : {:TOTAL=>311794, :FREE=>59829, :T_OBJECT=>6, :T_CLASS=>542, :T_MODULE=>100021, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>3332, :T_REGEXP=>22, :T_ARRAY=>23868, :T_HASH=>10, :T_BIGNUM=>3, :T_FILE=>3, :T_DATA=>100324, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>23807, :T_ICLASS=>19}
>
> 100000 MODULES GARBAGE COLLECTED
> WAITING TO END PROGRAM
>
> FINAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : {:TOTAL=>311794, :FREE=>107155, :T_OBJECT=>6, :T_CLASS=>542, :T_MODULE=>100021, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>3335, :T_REGEXP=>22, :T_ARRAY=>203, :T_HASH=>10, :T_BIGNUM=>3, :T_FILE=>3, :T_DATA=>100324, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>143, :T_ICLASS=>19}

Comment: try this http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html#method-c-start instead of `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect`. and let me know please.

Comment: For me, it yields the same value 21 - 31 - 31, using your code sample from your answer below (see comment there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `GC.start` or `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect` *does not* mean that a garbage collection will be performed. It's only a hint to the Ruby runtime.

On some platforms it isn't even *possible* for the Ruby runtime to initiate a garbage collection, because the garbage collector isn't even part of the Ruby runtime, e.g on JRuby or IronRuby.

In general, the Ruby runtime will decide on its own when it will perform a garbage collection. Usually, that's when it runs out of memory. 100000 modules aren't *that* big, so there's simply no need to perform a GC cycle.

Also, most Ruby implementations will *never* release memory back to the OS, even after a GC cycle.

So, just the fact that the `ObjectSpace` doesn't shrink doesn't necessarily mean that you have memory leak. It could simply mean that the Ruby runtime didn't yet deem it necessary to run a GC cycle.

Also note that if you run this code from IRb, Pry, an IDE console or some other non-standard environment, then it may be the case that *those* hold on to some of those modules. For example, Pry stores the results of the last 100 commands in a history array. (Try evaluating `_out_[5]` in Pry, after entering your example program.)

Comment: Yes in my answer `GC.start` worked partially,what I can understand by seeing the output of `puts "FINAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_MODULE]}"`.

Comment: Glad there's no 'structural' memory leak i couldn't avoid. What i'm doing is rather experimental so i don't mind when or even if memory is released, provided it's conceived to be released. So if you're saying that a non referenced anonymous module is eligible for GC regardless of the ruby implementation, your answer is as good as accepted as far as i'm concerned. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can Look into the method [**`GC#start`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html#method-c-start)

```
puts "INITIAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_MODULE]}"
i = 10
ms = []

i.times do
    ms << Module.new do
        def foo()
             puts('foo method called')
        end
    end
end

puts "#{i} MODULES CREATED" 
puts "OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_MODULE]}"


p ms
ms = nil
GC.start

puts "#{i} MODULES GARBAGE COLLECTED"
puts "WAITING TO END PROGRAM"
p ms 
puts "FINAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_MODULE]}"
```

***Output:***

```
INITIAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : 21
10 MODULES CREATED
OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : 31
[#<Module:0xe33a48>, #<Module:0xe338c8>, #<Module:0xe33808>, #<Module:0xe337a8>, #<Module:0xe33610>, 
#<Module:0xe334c0>, #<Module:0xe33328>, #<Module:0xe33250>, #<Module:0xe33118>, #<Module:0xe33088>]
10 MODULES GARBAGE COLLECTED
WAITING TO END PROGRAM
nil
FINAL OBJECT SPACE OBJECTS : 23
```

So you can see after garbage collection I got the final count as 23 instead of 21,which is exactly explained by **@Jörg W Mittag**.

Comment: Using your code T_MODULE count ends up with this same 31, not 23. Is that where the ruby implementation comes in ? Thanks for the help, but i'm not gonna mess around with GC and ObjectSpace. As stated above i just wanted to make sure modules and classes are REALLY normal objects, and as such are GCable.

Comment: And out of curiosity, where do those 2 extra items (23 - 21 = 2) come from ?

Comment: @ergosumcogito I don't think any extra comes out..as Jorg mentioned it recycling not happened as we are expecting in ruby always.. may be that's the reason..

Comment: ~ offtopic : Yeah, I remember a blogpost saying not to develop games in ruby, namely because of the state of the GC. Recycling has its limits they say... :)